# SAS: replace values in all variables if value is 99,98 or 0

Tags: sas

Preparing for an exam by looking at earlier assignments, this one is tricky for me:

```
`enter code here`data xxx.data001(drop=i);
    set xxx.data001;
        array nvr {*} _NUMERIC_;
            do i = 1 to dim(nvr);
                if nvr{i} in (99 98 0) then nvr{i} = .;
            end;
run;
```

I am asked to make a similar program without using arrays.

so far I've tried the replace function:

```
replace _ALL_ where(_ALL_ = 99 | 98 | 0)
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.!

Thank you

EDIT:

Thanks for the responses everyone - wonderful community!! :-)
Regarding the curriculum, I'm pretty sure I'm allowed to do whatever.. We have more or less autonomy in our learning.

Can someone explain what happens in this line:

```
if nvr{i} in (99 98 0) then nvr{i} = .;
```

Especially the "in" is confusing me. Are 99, 98 and 0 variables or values of observations?

Thank you

Comment: Is this a macro class, by chance?  Do you know the technique of generating a list of macro calls from PROC CONTENTS or DICTIONARY.COLUMNS or SASHELP.VCOLUMN?

Comment: FYI, `replace` is a statement, not a function, and is used in data steps with `modify`.

Comment: The `array` statement has created an array of all the numeric variables in your data set. The `do` loop runs the if statement for each of these variables. For the first iteration of the `do` loop, the statement run is `if nvr{1} in (99 98 0) then nvr{i} = .;`, where `nvr{1}` is the first variable in the array. `in` is an operator that checks whether the value of `nvr{1}` is equal to any one of the values in the parentheses. So if `nvr{1}` is equal to either 98, 99, or 0, then `nvr{1}` is set equal to `.` (missing).

Comment: Thanks - now I understand the "in" operator.. 
So instead of saying e.g
`if nvr(1) = 99 or 98 or 0 in nvr(1)` you write `nvr(1) in (99 98 0)` !

Comment: @FransRasmussen What I'm trying to get at is, what are you expected to show in this particular exercise.  What you posted above is generally the best way to do this; so if you're being asked to show a different way, you're probably being asked either a) to show what the non-array version would be [so some number of if statements, basically], or b) to use the macro language to produce the code above. Both would be inferior solutions, but it's possible that's what your exam is getting at.  However, this question is not a good question without that information.

Comment: @Joe to answer your question: My curriculum covers macros. IMHO the exam question is a bit out of touch. It would be better to have it "turned around", so i would need to make it with arrays. 

Anyhow - I needed help as to how one could get the number of variables existing in the data set, and use that to check each variable for missing 99, 98 and 0's..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Frans: As Joe points out below this is only useful to you if you have covered this material in your course.

Here is a macro approach. The major components of this solution are:

- A macro wrapper to enable the use of a `%do` loop
- `proc contents` to return a data set containing details of the variables in your data
- `proc sql` with `select into :` store data from a data set in a macro variable (some extra uses of the colon can be found [here](http://www2.sas.com/proceedings/sugi26/p073-26.pdf))
- `separated by " "` to create a space separated list
- A `%do` loop to iterate over each of the columns
- The `%sysfunc()` macro function to allow the calling of a data step function as part of a macro statement
- The `%scan()` macro function to extract the individual variable names from the list one at a time

---

```
/* Wrap the code in a macr so we can use %do loop */
%macro remove9899(data);
    /* Get all the columns information */
    proc contents data = &data. out = cols noprint;
    run;
    /* Store the numeric columns as a space seperated list in a macro variable */
    proc sql noprint;
        select name 
        into :cols separated by " "
        from cols
        where type = 1;
    quit;
    data &data.;
        set &data.;
        /* Loop through each numeric variable and make the conditional replacement */
        %do i = 1 %to %sysfunc(countw(&cols., %str( )));
            %let col = %scan(&cols., &i., %str( ));
            if &col. in (0, 98, 99) then &col = .;
        %end;
    run;
%mend remove9899;

%remove9899(xxx.data001);
```

Comment: I would avoid posting answers to homework/exam prep questions until/unless they clarify details like whether the class covers this kind of material.  Given the poster provides the best reasonable way to do this already, this answer isn't helpful unless it happens to coincide with what they're covering right now.

Comment: Agree with Joe.  Replacing the array and DO loop of the initial question with a %DO loop is, IMHO, a misuse of the macro language, when arrays are the better approach.  Imagine there are 100 variables.  Probably better to use an array with 100 elements and one IF statement, rather than generate 100 IF statements (though I haven't tested, admittedly).  Hopefully the OP has misunderstood their assignment.

Comment: @Joe I take your point, but feel that this provides the most sensible answer to the question as stated (I'd like to see other approaches posted if anybody has any). Furthermore, this provides a good launching point for learning a bit about macros. @Quentin, yes the array approach is cleaner, but I wouldn't call this a misuse of macros as the data step should be as efficient (same number of `if`s are evaluated) and the macro method would be better in slightly modified use cases (e.g. when you want to use `else if`, limit variables by a suffix or select a non adjacent subset of variables).

Comment: @SRSwift While I wouldn't do it this way - I don't like this method of programming - that part is just me, and I certainly think this is one way of doing this.  In this case, however, the issue is that it is a homework/exam prep question that asks how to do something in a manner other than the 'best'; those are generally 'not good questions' unless they are more specific in the ways I mention.